# Return specific rows from an array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a masterdata, which I update often. From this masterdata, I paste region specific data on seperate excel sheets. I do this by copying and pasting the data with the help of filtering.

Here is a sample of the masterdata (1st picture), and final product in which i filter the data to:
[image][image]

Is there a way to automate this? I.e., can I start using some formula that allows me to only update the masterdata in such a way that all the region sheets also update?

Comment: Use `FILTER()` Function if you are presently using `MS365` or `Excel 2021`.

Comment: Like Mayukh Bhattacharya commented, FILTER does exactly that. If your Excel version doesn't support that you need to use a combination of INDEX/AGGREGATE